# Why does my WPF application quit unexpectedly on Windows XP SP2?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, windows-xp

I've compiled my WPF project on Windows 7 64-bit, using VS 2010 and .NET 4. I have compiled it as a 32-bit application, of course, and it works fine in both 32- and 64-bit versions of Windows Vista/7.

But in Windows XP SP2 32-bit, I get an error:

> wpfApp has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience."

How can I fix this so that my application will run on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 4 requires Windows XP Service Pack 3.

Either [upgrade to SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5B33B5A8-5E76-401F-BE08-1E1555D4F3D4&displaylang=en), or downgrade your project to target .NET 3.5.

Comment: @user301639: Make sure you check all your references.If you are using libraries that are not in the .NET framework make sure you set Copy Local = true on the required reference properties. And also make sure that you compile all libraries and the application as the same CPU configuration. It might be problem with libraries.